# Angular2 route matching a specific value

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to find a way to show a specific component when url has only a specific value.
Basically this is how is looking the routing now:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '1',
            component: NeedToRenderThisComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: DashboardComponent
          },
          {
            path: '',
            outlet: 'sidebar',
            component: SidebarComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So what I am looking for is when user hits or enters another way on '/users/1', user will see NeedToRenderThisComponent. For all others values there will be DashboardComponent.

DashboardComponent contains two router outlets

```
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `path: '**'` route and then add the component yourself like shown in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468).

AFAIK there is no way to match values. There were regex routes in an older router but in the current router this is not (yet?) implemented.

**update**

Support for custom path matchers have landed and will probably be available with the next update
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12442

Comment: So basically thiss will match everything and will render the component, and then in component I will render dynamically components based on the url, am I right?

Comment: Exactly, that was my idea.

Comment: Seems support for custom path matches has landed. See my updated answer.